# Trying to call different class's variable but java reflection does not work

Tags: android, exploit, android-security, mobile-security

I am trying out a challenge where the system has an app installed from which I need to extract a variable called x.
The app has a man-in-the-disk vulnerability where it calls a file in the external storage. I replaced this file and now I am trying with this file to extract the variable. I tried java reflection but I was getting ClassNotFound exception.

```
    public class Abc {
    public static void run() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

        Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName("com.system.app.MainActivity");
        Field xField = classToLoad.getDeclaredField("x");
        xField.setAccessible(true);

        // Access the value of the field\n" +
        String xValue = (String) xField.get(null);            // Print
        Log.d("x", "Value of MainActivity.x: " + xValue);
    }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I just need to extract x from com.system.app; if not java reflection what do I do?